# How To Go back to previous version of Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I had created an Ionic project ago. Now my Ionic is updated. I want to go back to old version to make some changes to the project. It is showing error.

This is the version of my ionic project:

[image]

This is the error I get when installing ionic:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"ionic-bower" is not a NPM package. You cannot use npm to install it using the npm command line, or through the package.json.

"ionic-bower" is a bower package.  You can install it using bower.  After installing the bower package manager, try something like from your command line:

```
bower install driftyco/ionic-bower#v1.3.3
```

After downloading Ionic with bower, you'll probably have a bower_components folder created in the directory you ran the command under. And in that directory, there will be an Ionic directory. That old version of Ionic is just a JS+CSS library.  Not the Ionic-CLI.

If you want to download old(er) version of Ionic using NPM, you can run this command to get a list of old versions.

```
npm view ionic versions --json
```

You would have to know what version of Ionic you want.  But if an old version of Ionic references an old version of another dependency, you simply may not able to install that old version of Ionic. You can attempt to install any of the old(er) versions with this command:

```
npm install -g ionic@2.0.0
```

Replacing 2.0.0 is whatever version you need.

Seriously consider using a new version of Ionic. You'll be better off.

That's all the help I can give you. Hope this helps.

Comment: I installed the above code. its is successfully done. But when i check for ionic -v its showing 'ionic' is not recognised..@Steve Kennedy

Comment: sir let me explain my problem. I have developed projects in ionic previously. Now ionic is updated and i am not able to change anything on the previous projects. Build is not successful.I need to go back to previous and install ionic globally. so that i can continue with changes. please add me on skype-Ranendra.Softnet

Comment: i have 2 ionic projects. How can i Know in which ionic version these projects are created? And I highly appreciate your help. thanks